# Rails WHERE query on has_many relation works incorrect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Cheers!
Let's say I have `User` that `has_many` `Accounts`, `Account` model has `logged_in (boolean)` field.

I wrote a AR query:
`User.joins(:accounts).where(accounts: { logged_in: false })`, right?

But then I check it `User.joins(:accounts).where(accounts: { logged_in: false }).first.accounts.pluck(:logged_in)`
And could see that there are some accounts with `mobiles.logged_in = true` values.

```
(0.1ms)  SELECT "accounts"."logged_in" FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 373]]
false
false
true
```

Why?

Comment: `mobiles` is different from `accounts`, right?

Comment: @ollpu sorry, that a typo, I meant `accounts`, that's not a source of problem

Comment: @Nikita - It works perfect. Try and think. Why do you expect that user to have only logged_in false accounts when you just find users based on that same condition. It is just a `user` object  `User.joins(:accounts).where(accounts: { logged_in: false }).first` upto here. And then calling `accounts` on it will return `all` accounts associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.joins(:accounts).where(accounts: { logged_in: false })
```

fetches all users that have **at least** one account with `logged_in == false`.
That's because it gets translated to (roughly):

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN accounts
WHERE users.id = accounts.user_id
  AND NOT accounts.logged_in
```

---

The problem is that when you do

```
User.joins(:accounts).where(accounts: { logged_in: false }).first.accounts
```

you're actually re-fetching all accounts for the first user you found, logged_in or not.
 This user does have at least one `NOT logged_in` account, but not necessarily all of them.